# Hiding real ip adress in Linux ubunto

Tags: ip, filtering, vpn

Hi good evening to all

Brothers, is there a way to hide our real ip adress in Linux server ubunto? I mean I want it to literally doesn't show it by pinging it or I done know using a ip check website on my domain

Cuase I made a  VPN and I want my ip adress hidden so it could not be filtered

If anyone has any idea it would help me and my country a lot

Thank you.

Please tell me any idea and commands you think it would work and I will test them